# Do I need an SSP to search in many web applications within a same farm?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I am working on a farm with 2 web servers with many web applications, and I need to search for content in the 2 servers.
Do I need to setup a SSP if the servers are in the same farm? Many thanks. (MOSS 2007)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need SSP to enable multi-site searching in MOSS 2007. WSS only provides site level search only.